# Schedule the UILocalNotifiation on same day swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to schedule the UILocalNotifications.
The functionality i want to implement is that to repeat the notification on a perticular day, like (every monday) which will be selected by the user.
Is there any way to schedule the UILocalNotification so the notification will be trigger on that day only.

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()

let dict:NSDictionary = ["ID" : "your ID goes here"]
notification.userInfo = dict as! [String : String]
notification.alertBody = "\(title)"
notification.alertAction = "Open"
notification.fireDate = dateToFire
notification.repeatInterval = .Day  // Can be used to repeat the notification
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: Yes, first create your buttons to select the day you want to fire LocalNotification.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a weekly by doing:

```
notification.repeatInterval = .Weekday // Or maybe .WeekOfYear
```

Whatever day of the week `dateToFire` is, the notification will be repeated once a week on that day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure this will help you, but I have worked with this before. I create 7 buttons to select 7 days in a week. This is my old code:

```
class RemindNotification {

  var timerNotification = NSTimer()

  func notification(story: Story) {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let date = NSDate()

    let dateComponents = calendar!.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth, NSCalendarUnit.Month,NSCalendarUnit.Year,NSCalendarUnit.Hour,NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate:date)
    dateComponents.hour = story.remindeAtHour
    dateComponents.minute = story.remindeAtMinute
    for index in 0..<story.remindeAtDaysOfWeek.count {
      if story.remindeAtDaysOfWeek[index] == true {
        if index != 6{
          dateComponents.weekday = index + 2
          fireNotification(calendar!, dateComponents: dateComponents)
        } else {
          dateComponents.weekday = 1
          fireNotification(calendar!, dateComponents: dateComponents)
        }
      } else {
        dateComponents.weekday = 0
      }
    }
  }

  func fireNotification(calendar: NSCalendar, dateComponents: NSDateComponents) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertAction = "Title"
    notification.alertBody = "It's time to take a photo"
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
    notification.fireDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
  }
}
```

This is for my App, I can choose the day, and then it can fire LocalNotification at the specific time that I set in each day.

You can refer to it. Hope this help.